# .bat file %date% wrong output in windows server 2008

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2008

I'm using `%date:~10%%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%` for date

The output should be like : 201706161102

but the output : 016.1102

whats wrong?

Comment: date format is dependent on the localization settings.To get the date independent from settings in the control panel check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/19799236/388389

Comment: Your server has a different date configuration to that which you expected. What is the value of `ECHO "%DATE%"`

Comment: @Compo 16.06.2017

Comment: Based upon that output you could use `%DATE:~-4%%DATE:~-7,2%%DATE:~-10,2%%TIME:~0,2%%TIME:~3,2%` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you using the output of the `WMIC` command like that :

```bat
@echo off
Title Get Date and Time with WMIC
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%"
set "MM=%dt:~4,2%"
set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%"
set "Min=%dt:~10,2%"
set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"
echo YYYYMMDDHHMinSec
Set "DateTimeVar=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%%HH%%Min%%Sec%"
echo %DateTimeVar%
pause
```